# Does F7 not work in Powershell 7 to show command history?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

In Powershell 5.1, one could press <kbd>F7</kbd> and a history of previous entered commands would show up.  I just intalled Powershell 7.2 and <kbd>F7</kbd> no longer does anything. <kbd>F8</kbd> still autocompletes based on command history though.

Comment: Cross-stack relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376858/make-command-history-pop-up-work-via-f7-in-windows-10-powershell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### <kbd>F7</kbd> no longer does anything in PowerShell 7.

By default it doesn't do anything. However read on ...

`Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` lists all of the available keyboard short cuts and as of PowerShell 7 <kbd>F7</kbd> is not longer included in the list of history functions:

```
History functions
=================
Key       Function              Description
---       --------              -----------
Alt+F7    ClearHistory          Remove all items from the command line history (not PowerShell history)
Ctrl+s    ForwardSearchHistory  Search history forward interactively
F8        HistorySearchBackward Search for the previous item in the history that starts with the current input - like PreviousHistory if the input is empty
Shift+F8  HistorySearchForward  Search for the next item in the history that starts with the current input - like NextHistory if the input is empty
DownArrow NextHistory           Replace the input with the next item in the history
UpArrow   PreviousHistory       Replace the input with the previous item in the history
Ctrl+r    ReverseSearchHistory  Search history backwards interactively
```

The about output is from running `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`on PowerShell 7.2.2

Oddly enough <kbd>F7</kbd> **is** still listed in the Microsoft documentation at [about History - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_history?view=powershell-7.2) so it **should** work.

---

#### The Plot Thickens

> **It does still work, it just does not work in combination with the
> `PSReadLine` module** <sup>(1)</sup>. I am not sure if this is documented anywhere but
> you can run the following:
>
> `Remove-Module -Name PSReadLine`
>
> After this cmdlet you will be able to <kbd>F7</kbd> your heart out
> again, but you'll miss out on all the fancy colors ;)
>
> Please note that `Remove-Module` does not actually delete the module,
> it simply unload it from the current session.

<sup>(1) emphasis mine</sup>

Source [F7 History no longer in Windows 10 AU? : PowerShell](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4x5iig/f7_history_no_longer_in_windows_10_au/)

There is an open bug report at [Please allow F7 to work · Issue #620 · PowerShell/PSReadLine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/620)

---

#### Workaround

You can use the following script.

> You can add your own <kbd>F7</kbd> in PSReadline by using the
> `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler` cmdlet in a script. Example:
>
> ```
> Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key F7 -BriefDescription "History" -LongDescription "Show command history" -ScriptBlock {
>   $pattern = $null
>   [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref] $pattern, [ref] $null)
>   if ( $pattern ) {
>     $pattern = [Regex]::Escape($pattern)
>   }
>   $history = [System.Collections.ArrayList] @(
>     $last = ""
>     $lines = ""
>     foreach ( $line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath) )
>       {
>       if ( $line.EndsWith('`') ) {
>         $line = $line.Substring(0, $line.Length - 1)
>         $lines = if ( $lines ) { "$lines`n$line" } else { $line }
>         continue
>       }
>       if ( $lines ) {
>         $line = "$lines`n$line"
>         $lines = ""
>       }
>       if ( ($line -cne $last) -and ((-not $pattern) -or ($line -match $pattern)) ) {
>         $last = $line
>         $line
>       }
>     }
>   )
>   $command = $history | Out-GridView -Title History -PassThru
>   if ( $command ) {
>     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()
>     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert(($command -join "`n"))
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> When you use this function, the <kbd>F7</kbd> key will appear in a
> pop-up grid view window. Select a history entry and press
> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and PowerShell will put it on the command line for
> editing.

Source [Make Command-History Pop-Up work via F7 in Windows 10 Powershell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376858/make-command-history-pop-up-work-via-f7-in-windows-10-powershell/50382377#50382377), answer by [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart)

See also [Use F7 as "Show Command History" in Powershell](https://gist.github.com/tig/cbbeab7f53efd73e329afd6d4b838191) for a similar workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I developed the "F7 History" PowerShell Module to address this:

Install `F7History` from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/F7History/).

```
Install-Module -Name "F7History"
```

Add a line to import `F7History` in your PowerShell `$profile`:

```
Import-Module -Name "F7History"
```

At the PowerShell command line:

- Press `F7` to see the history for the current PowerShell instance.
- Press `Shift-F7` to see the history for all PowerShell instances.

Whatever was typed on the command line before hitting `F7` or `Shift-F7` will be used for the `Out-ConsoleGridView` `-Filter`` parameter.

When the `Command Line History` window is displayed:

- Use the arrow keys or mouse to select an item.
- Use `ENTER` to insert the selected item on the command line.
- Use `ESC` to close the window without inserting anything on the command line.

Comment: You neglected to mention that you are the author, so its looking **spam**. Please read the help on self promotion.

Comment: @RohitGupta I appreciate you calling this out. I should have been clear that I authored this. To be fair, this question was one of the things that motivated me to update F7History to be easier to install. I've updated my answer to make it clear I wrote F7History.